# Does bitcoin-qt support jsonrpc?

Tags: backup

After some time away, and a dead Vista PC, I have come back to Bitcoin and installed the latest (0.5.1-beta) on Windows 7. (Don't worry, I didn't lose my wallet.)

On my old machine, using bitcoin.exe, I was able to connect on port 8332 and send a jsonrpc command to back up my wallet. However, I have now forgotten the command-line parameters (if any) I used for this.

Here are the (redacted) contents of my bitcoin.conf file:

```
rpcuser=xxxxxxxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxxxxxxxx
gen=0
rpcallowip=192.168.2.6
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
paytxfee=0.01
```

The principal symptom is this (from python):

> IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it

Using bitcoind.exe, however, "it all works".

Any suggestions?

(BTW sorry for the weak tag; I don't have enough karma to create my own)

Answer (score 3):

After reading [the fine manual,](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf) I added these lines to bitcoin.conf:

```
server=1
rpcport=8332
```

and it appears to be working.